# Converting Year, Month, Day to momentjs Unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp, momentjs

I'm trying to get the same value as `1502755200000` using momentjs

```
console.log(Date.UTC(2017, (8-1), 15));//1502755200000

var newDate = moment();
newDate.set('year', 2017);
newDate.set('month', 7);  // April
newDate.set('date', 15);

console.log(newDate.format('X'));//1502818350
```

However when I try to get the miliseconds I get `1502818350` Any idea how to get the exact same timestamp as above?

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cdvzoezb/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, `.format('X')` gives you the unix timestamp in seconds, not milliseconds.
To get milliseconds, you must use `.format('x')` (lowercase x).

Secondly, when you use `moment()`, it gives you a moment date object at your current *local* time, not UTC time. So when you modify it with `.set('date', 15)` etc, you're setting it to 15 April 2017 in your *local* time. This is why you're getting the vastly different value.

To get a moment date object for current UTC time, use `moment.utc()`.

Thirdly, the Date object you created will be at time 00:00:00.000, while the moment object will be for current time. So when you set the year/month/date, time still remains at what it was when you created the object. You need to set the moment object's time to 00:00:00.000.

This can be done with the `.startOf('day')` function.

In conclusion:

```
console.log(Date.UTC(2017, (8-1), 15)); //1502755200000

var newDate = moment.utc();
newDate.set('year', 2017);
newDate.set('month', 7);
newDate.set('date', 15);
newDate.startOf('day');

console.log(newDate.format('x')); //1502755200000
```

Or, much shorter:

```
var newDate = moment.utc('2017-07-15 00:00:00.000');
```

Comment: Hey Aakash thanks for the explanation! I ran your code on a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fuxmbga2/ and I am still getting a different timestamp. Any idea why?

Comment: Thank you very much for you detailed answer Aakash!

Comment: Or even shorter: `moment('2017-08-15T00:00:00.000Z')`. ;-) BTW, Date objects are inherently UTC. moment objects can have an associated timezone that is used for calculations and formatting, but the underlying Date object is UTC.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can simply create a moment object out of a `Date` instance and then using the `utc()` to convert the timestamp to UTC. After that, we can use moments method `format()` to get milliseconds using the `x` display option like so:

```
console.log("==============");
console.log(Date.UTC(2017, (8-1), 15));
var base = Date.UTC(2017, (8-1), 15)
var newDate = moment(base);

console.log('a', newDate.utc().format('x')); //1502755200000
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The asker wanted to know why his `moment` object does not yield the same timestamp as the equivalent `Date`